# required to use append function in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

```
function readDataFromRange() {
  //Read data from the range OPTION CHAIN - NIFTY!D1:G1
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("OPTION CHAIN - NIFTY!D1:G1").getValues();

  //Log the data that was read.
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));

  //Write the data to the range A1:D1 in Sheet "GRAPHDATA"
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("GRAPHDATA!A1:D1").setValues(data);

  //apennd the rows 
  
  }
```

I am trying to fetch the data from one sheet and write it another sheet.I wish to append the destination sheet so as to aufill data in destination cell.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly and you wish to append the data to the destination sheet, you can try

```js
function readDataFromRange() {
  //Read data from the range OPTION CHAIN - NIFTY!D1:G1
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const data = ss.getRange("OPTION CHAIN - NIFTY!D1:G1").getValues().flat();

  //Log the data that was read.
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));

  //Append data to Sheet "GRAPHDATA"
  ss.getSheetByName("GRAPHDATA").appendRow(data)
}
```

### Reference

- [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Comment: I tried to code but it didnt worked .The script ran but no ouput in GRAPHDATA sheet.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet (sensitive data erased) so I can have a closer look?